# How to obtain sub-totals grouping only by one column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If I have a table like:

```
LOCATION         CODE       COMPANY            PRICE
---------        ----       -------       ----------
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |          1200
Brisbane     |    C    |    WONKA    |          3000
Melbourne    |    B    |    ACME     |           500
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |           100
Brisbane     |    A    |    WONKA    |          1000
Melbourne    |    C    |    ACME     |          7000
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |           800
Brisbane     |    B    |    WONKA    |           900
Melbourne    |    C    |    WONKA    |           200
Sydney       |    C    |    ACME     |           400
Brisbane     |    B    |    ACME     |          1200
Melbourne    |    D    |    WONKA    |           600
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |          3000
Brisbane     |    A    |    WONKA    |           400
Melbourne    |    C    |    WONKA    |          1400
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |          1600
Brisbane     |    A    |    WONKA    |           700
Melbourne    |    A    |    ACME     |           800
```

and I want to obtain something like:

```
LOCATION         CODE       COMPANY         SUM(PRICE)
---------        ----       -----           ----------
Brisbane     |    A    |    WONKA    |          2100
Brisbane     |    B    |    ACME     |          1200
Brisbane     |    B    |    WONKA    |           900
Brisbane     |    C    |    WONKA    |          3000
Brisbane     |         |             |          7200 
Melbourne    |    A    |    ACME     |           800
Melbourne    |    B    |    ACME     |           500
Melbourne    |    C    |    ACME     |          7000
Melbourne    |    C    |    WONKA    |          1600
Melbourne    |    D    |    WONKA    |           600
Melbourne    |         |             |         10500
Sydney       |    A    |    ACME     |          6700
Sydney       |    C    |    ACME     |           400
Sydney       |         |             |          7100
```

That is the price totals grouped by location, code and company, with a price sub-total row (grouped by location only).

The first part can be achieved  with the following query:

```
with sample_tab as
(
select 'Sydney' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 1200 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'C' code, 'WONKA' company, 3000 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'B' code, 'ACME' company, 500 price from dual
union all
select 'Sydney' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 100 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'A' code, 'WONKA' company, 1000 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'C' code, 'ACME' company, 7000 price from dual
union all
select 'Sydney' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 800 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'B' code, 'WONKA' company, 900 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'C' code, 'WONKA' company, 200 price from dual
union all
select 'Sydney' location,'C' code, 'ACME' company, 400 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'B' code, 'ACME' company, 1200 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'D' code, 'WONKA' company, 600 price from dual
union all
select 'Sydney' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 3000 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'A' code, 'WONKA' company, 400 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'C' code, 'WONKA' company, 1400 price from dual
union all
select 'Sydney' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 1600 price from dual
union all
select 'Brisbane' location,'A' code, 'WONKA' company, 700 price from dual
union all
select 'Melbourne' location,'A' code, 'ACME' company, 800 price from dual
)
select location,code,company,sum(price)
from sample_tab
group by location,code,company
order by location;
```

but not sure how to obtain the rows with the sub-totals by location.
Can this be achieved using rollup analytical functions or other functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want what are called "rollup totals" - but only for one column. That is a partial rollup. Moreover, you want the totals for each pair of (code, company) but not for each individual code or individual company. That is possible in the Oracle `rollup` syntax, with what is technically a "composite column" (the syntax is to enclose the pair within its own parentheses, besides the parentheses required for rollup). Replace the double-parentheses after the keyword `rollup` with single parentheses and compare the result - that will **not** be what you want.

So, here is the query:

```
select   location,code,company,sum(price)
from     sample_tab
group by location,rollup((code,company))   -- partial rollup on composite column
order by location,code,company;            -- add code and company to order by
```

Comment: Yes... exactly what I was after. Many thanks!... I knew about rollup, but not about composite columns.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution or for future users who wants to implement in other databases without `rollup`

```
sums as (
select  location, code, company,sum(price) price
from sample_tab
group by  location, code, company),
subgroup as (
select  location, '','', sum(price) price
from sample_tab
group by  location) 
select *
from sums
union all
select *
from subgroup
order by location;
```